# How to sort an array by date into angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I get data from my database, I insert it into an array and I display the array. Now I want to display the array from the most recent to the oldest date. I put my code below, but it does not work, there is no error but it does not sort

```
this.perturbationsBDDFavorite.push({
                      id : doc.data().id,
                      userId: doc.data().userId,
                      nomAgence: doc.data().nomAgence,
                      icon: doc.data().icon,
                      numero:doc.data().numero,
                      depart: doc.data().depart,
                      arrive: doc.data().arrive,
                      horaireDepart:doc.data().horaireDepart,
                      horaireArrive:doc.data().horaireArrive,
                      suppression: doc.data().suppression,
                      retard: doc.data().retard,
                      suggestion: doc.data().suggestion,
                      vehiculeSurcharge: doc.data().vehiculeSurcharge,
                      proprete: doc.data().proprete,
                      securite: doc.data().securite,
                      tempsDeclaration: doc.data().tempsDeclaration,
                      dateDeclaration: doc.data().dateDeclaration,
                      timeRetard: doc.data().timeRetard,
                      commentaire: doc.data().commentaire,
                      status: doc.data().status,
                      urlfacebook: doc.data().urlfacebook,
                      userDeleted: doc.data().userDeleted
                    });
                    console.log(this.perturbationsBDDFavorite);
                    for(let i = 0; i < this.perturbationsBDDFavorite.length; i++){

                    this.perturbationsFavorite = this.perturbationsBDDFavorite.sort((val1, val2) =>{
                      val1.dateDeclaration =  new Date(val1.dateDeclaration.seconds*1000);
                      val2.dateDeclaration = new Date(val2.dateDeclaration.seconds*1000);
                      return Math.abs(val1.dateDeclaration.getSeconds() - val2.dateDeclaration.getSeconds());
                    } )
                    }
                    }
```

Comment: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-sort-array-by-date-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code after you insert data in array no need for the loop. It seems like your dates are not dates but timestamps so you can just compare them as is.

```
this.perturbationsBDDFavorite
    .sort((val1, val2) => {
      if (val1.dateDeclaration > val2.dateDeclaration) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (val1.dateDeclaration < val2.dateDeclaration) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
```